# calculator Java adding numbers

Tags: java

So, my question is, how do I turn this make my calculator app be able to take input like this, 100 * 2 / 2 + 5 and make it return the sum of it?
or maybe even somehow make it use ( ) brackets..?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter number: ");
        String input = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter number 2: ");
        String input2 = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter operator ");
        String op = scanner.nextLine();

        int intEnter1 = Integer.parseInt(input.toString());
        int intEnter2 = Integer.parseInt(input2.toString());

        if (op.contains("+")) {
            System.out.println(intEnter1 + intEnter2);
        }

        if (op.contains("-")) {
            System.out.println(intEnter1 - intEnter2);
        }

        if (op.contains("*")) {
            System.out.println(intEnter1 * intEnter2);
        }

        if (op.contains("/")) {
            double intEnter1Double = (double) intEnter1;
            double intEnter2Double = (double) intEnter2;
            System.out.println(intEnter1Double / intEnter2Double);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you want to achieve is going to include a lot more code, and since SO isn't a code-writing service, you need to either ask a more specific question, or just try stuff out.

Comment: You need to turn the expression from infix notation to reverse Polish notation and then evaluate it. It's a well-known problem and many tutorials and examples exist, so you should start there and ask a specific question here when you hit a roadblock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert your expression to [Reverse Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation). 
The idea is to transform complex expression to such form that it will be possible to calculate the result using the following algorithm:

1. expression is parsed from left to right
2. numbers are pushed to stack
3. if an operator occured, the correspondent amount of numbers a popped
           from stack (1 for unary operator, 2 for binary) and the operation is performed on them

For example, given the input:

```
5 + ((1 + 2) × 4) − 3
```

the notation will as following:

```
5 1 2 + 4 × + 3 −
```

Answer (score 3):

There is also a very good library for evaluating math expressions called [exp4j](http://www.objecthunter.net/exp4j/#Evaluating_an_expression).

You can do something like this:

```
Expression e = new ExpressionBuilder("3 * sin(y) - 2 / (x - 2)")
    .variables("x", "y")
    .build()
    .setVariable("x", 2.3)
    .setVariable("y", 3.14);
double result = e.evaluate();
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a library that makes that evaluate expressions. You can try this.

http://javaluator.sourceforge.net/en/home/

```
Double value = new DoubleEvaluator().evaluate(expression);
```

But this library make all work for you and maybe you want to do by yourself the algorithm no?

Comment: Thanks you I will use